# How to make decorative details like wood carvings?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm attempting to make an old clock, but progress has slowed as I have absolutely no idea how to correctly make this:

[image: reference image]

I tried replicating the design via some faces with a solidify modifier and then a subdivide modifier, however, this does not look true to life.

[image: model]

Comment: Yes I guess you need to model it, not sure about the Solidify though, instead give it somme inner edges and pull to give thickness

Comment: This is a highly complex topic, and one of the most challenging type of things to model. There are people who dedicate their entire lives to perfecting modelling barroque style ornaments https://www.youtube.com/@1DInciner

Comment: The most apparent issue is the topology, which will affect both the smooth shaded normals and the behavior of subdivision.  The lowest effort solution to topology issues is, use more vertices: that is, consider dynotopo sculpting, or possibly curve objects and booleans, or a combination of techniques like that.  This will leave you with a very high poly object, with defects still visible on edges on magnification-- but then, you retopologize (and possibly bake normals.)  For objects like this, automated remeshing tools like Exoside Quad Remesher should work reasonably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/3sEBu2lZbOM

(30 characters--)

Answer (score 2):

Draw the contour but also create some inner edges in order to prepare the volume:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Pull the inner edges to give it 3D relief, etc:

[image]